# WSO2 maven build faild with version mvn 3.0.5-17 - test plugging issue

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

When I build WSO2 EI project using mvn clean install it showing following error message. It is showing Test plugins issue.

I have used following maven version

Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M2:test
>   (default-test) on project Supplier_Intergration_Handler_API: Execution
>   default-test of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M2:test failed:
>   Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components)
>   from the plugin
>   'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M2':
>   com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

Comment: Which version of WSO2 EI you are trying to build?

Comment: I have used wso2ei-6.4.0

Comment: Does the machine which runs the build has access to the internet? Also, please provide the java version, git repo and git branch you are trying to build?

Comment: I have updated java version to 1.8.0_111 and updated maven to 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64. Now working fine. Previously I have used open jdk